# Webview context doesn't show up anymore when testing using Appium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, appium, appium-android

I am creating an automation test using [Appium](https://appium.io/) and [webdriverio](https://webdriver.io/):

```
const wdio = require("webdriverio");

const opts = {
    path: "/wd/hub",
    port: 4723,
    capabilities: {
        platformName: "Android",
        platformVersion: "11",
        deviceName: "Android Emulator",
        app: "/path/to/myapk.apk",
        automationName: "UiAutomator2",
        autoGrantPermissions: true
    }
};

async function main() {
    const driver = await wdio.remote(opts);

    const contexts = await driver.getContexts();
    console.log("Contexts:", contexts);

    await driver.deleteSession();
}

main();
```

#### The problem

When running tests I could see that I used to have two contexts:

- `NATIVE_APP`
- `WEBVIEW_chrome` (or similar, I do not remember exactly the value here)

I then made a change which switched contexts to the webview, there I got an error about the chrome driver not being found. That is when I installed it: `npm install "appium-chromedriver"`.

I do not know if this is what made everything go babanas, but since then, everytime I test, I can only see the native context, no more webview context :(

#### More info

It is important to point out that I have modified my Android app to include this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
}
```

I can also start `chrome://inspect` and see the webview is there and even inspect it. But when running tests, the driver cannot see the webview context.

Why? How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I need to wait for a webview to show up in the app, so this works:

```
async function main() {
    const driver = await wdio.remote(opts);

    // Wait a few seconds so the webview properly loads
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));

    const contexts = await driver.getContexts();
    console.log("Contexts:", contexts);

    await driver.deleteSession();
}
```